# Mutt, Gmail, multiple accounts

Tags: gmail, mutt

I have currently setup Gmail as my unified Inbox. Mail from several accounts gets forwarded to it and I heavily use Gmail's 'send as' feature (Where gmail connects to a smtp server and sends the mail over the other account for me).

Now my question is whether it is possible to use this feature from within mutt without having to set up imap & smtp access to my other accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370)

> ".... you can use Gmail's outbound
>   servers with a different "from"
>   address. If you've already configured
>   the alternate address, your message
>   will be sent
>   from:otheraddress@domain.com,
>   sender:username@gmail.com, regardless
>   of which custom from configuration you
>   chose."

and you can [set the from address in mutt](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Header) by

> The primary way to set your default
>   sender address is through the $from
>   and $realname variables in muttrc:
>
> set realname="Joe User"  set
>   from="user@host"  set use_from=yes

Comment: This doesn't work with the "own SMTP server" configuration in Gmail. The message is sent directly from Gmail's to recipient's servers.

Comment: I was under the send as was the one where gmail sends e mails with an 'on behalf of' flag?

Comment: "Where gmail connects to a smtp server and sends the mail over the other account for me"